# Trying to read a database C# Errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to read from my SQL database however I am getting the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\\Work Practise\\Keepmefit\Keepmefit\\App_Data\Keepmefit.Models.CardioDBssContext.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'

I have attached the code below. I have done some breakpoints on my code and the exception is coming from `connection.Open();`

I have spent all day on this and have tried a lot of different ways however nothing seems to be working. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class StrengthController : Controller
{
    private const string VV = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Work Practise\\Keepmefit\Keepmefit\\App_Data\Keepmefit.Models.CardioDBssContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    // GET: Rep
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       // SqlDataReader read = null;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(VV);

        using (connection)
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Strength",
                                                connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader read = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (read.HasRows)
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Working" + read["Id"].ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("nothing");
            }
            read.Close();
        }
        return View();
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the file is in the right place? Did you make sure the user that the site is running as has the correct permissions to open the file?

Comment: I believe the issue might be D:\\.  It should be D:\.  The string is already prefixed with `@` so you don't need to escape the slashes.

Comment: Thank you @Amy for your response. The exception message how now disappeared. The next issue how is that the console.writeline for Id is not displaying anything into the console. Can anyone see a reason why it is not doing this? Thanks

Comment: @Leon The simplest explanation is often the correct one: you have no rows of data.  You can debug your code now.  Set a breakpoint and inspect what is happening.

Comment: @Amy I do, I have 4 rows of data in my SQLTable, I inserted a break point into the code again and the While loops through exactly 4 times which is why I'm curious as to why nothing is displaying

Comment: This looks like ASP.Net code.  Do you even *have* a console window?  Switch your code from `Console.` to `Debug.` and open the output window in VS.  Don't rely on Console in an ASP.Net app.

Comment: @Amy I just realized this! Thank you for your help. I have been staring at this all day with no avail. Finally got it sorted and it is displaying in the debug output!

Comment: @Leon Good deal, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the double backslashes in the connection string. When you define a string with a leading 'at' (`@`) character like this:

```
string VV = @"C:\some\file\path";
```

That is called a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim), and the backslash (`\`) characters don't have any special meaning to the language. Doubling them up gives you a string that really does have two backslashes, and that can break your file path.

In some cases, if you just send a path with extra `\` characters like that on to the file system you still end up okay, but for this situation I suspect the extra backslash is fooling the connection object that you're trying to connect to a file share path (ie: `\\server\share`), which is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Joel, I followed Amy's advice above and now the error has disappeared. The next issue now is that where the Console.Writeline is for reading the Id is not displaying on the console. Do you know any reason why it would not do this?

Comment: @Leon No rows available.

Comment: Fixed a type-o. The ampersand character is `&`.